# Targeting <img> by alt attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code. I want to find out why I am not able to target the `<img>` tag which only has the "award logos" `alt`

```
<img src="http://www.....jpg" alt="award logos">
<img src="http://www.....jpg" alt="Ranking">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img [alt="award logos"]').wrap("<a href='http://google.com' </a>");
});
</script>
```

Technically, what I want to do is targeting all the images that has the specific alt attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove space between `img` and `[alt="award logos"]` because of the space it is looking for child element of `img` with attribute `[alt="award logos"]`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img[alt="award logos"]').wrap("<a href='http://google.com'> </a>");
});
```

**NOTE** - you missed `>` for `a` (anchor) tag while wrapping `img`, please correct it.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r2eqeL2a/)**